# ASP.NET5 MVC 6 routing with optional parameter / default parameter value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I'm building Restful style API in VS2015, C#, ASP.NET5 MVC6 stack and I having some trouble when it comes to routing.

I'm using attributes directly in controller:

```
[HttpGet("machine/{machineId}-{cnt:int}")]
public IActionResult GetReportsByMachineId(string machineId, int cnt)
{
    var item = _reportRepository.GetReportsByMachineId(machineId, 0, cnt);
    if ((item == null) || (!item.Any()) )
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return new ObjectResult(item);
}
```

and it works when I call `api/report/machine/[machineName]-5` - I receive `5` documents from the database.

But I would like to make `cnt` parameter optional with default value - so the call for `api/report/machine/[machineName]` would be valid.

Based on http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/02/07/asp-net-5-deep-dive-routing I've tried so far:

`[HttpGet("machine/{machineId}-{cnt:int=10}")]` - controller don't catch `api/machine/{machineName}` (I get welcome page code)

`[HttpGet("machine/{machineId}-{cnt?}")]` - app wont start (I don't even get MVC welcome page)

`[HttpGet("machine/{machineId}-{cnt:int?}")]` - app wont start (like above)

Any ideas?

Code for whole controller (I don't have any other routes specified):
http://pastebin.pl/view/11050284

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**[Optional URI Parameters and Default Values](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#optional)**

You can make a URI parameter optional by adding a question mark to the route parameter. If a route parameter is optional, you must define a default value for the method parameter.

```
[HttpGet("machine/{machineId}/{cnt:int?}")]
public IActionResult GetReportsByMachineId(string machineId, int cnt = 10) {...}
```

In this example, `api/report/machine/nazwa_maszyny/10` and `api/report/machine/nazwa_maszyny` return the same resource.

Alternatively, you can specify a default value inside the route template, as follows:

```
[HttpGet("machine/{machineId}/{cnt:int=10}")]
public IActionResult GetReportsByMachineId(string machineId, int cnt) {...}
```

This is almost the same as the previous example, but there is a slight difference of behavior when the default value is applied.

- In the first example ("{cnt:int?}"), the default value of 10 is assigned directly to the method parameter, so the parameter will have this exact value.
- In the second example ("{cnt:int=10}"), the default value of "10" goes through the model-binding process. The default model-binder will convert "10" to the numeric value 10. However, you could plug in a custom model binder, which might do something different.

Comment: Thank You. So the problem was with the delimiter? I was using "-" and as long as the parameters were obligatory it worked.

Comment: that is correct. the frame work know to remove the `/`, but the `-` would not be removed automatically. you would have had to use the machine name with the dash, which is not optional